# OMNet++: What are the differens between ethg and pppg gates?

Tags: networking, network-programming, simulation, omnet++

I have searched OMNet++ manual but i couldn't found any information about gates. What are the differences between ethg and pppg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ethg is Ethernet and pppg is PPP

The difference of these two layer2 protocols you can look up on wikipedia.
E.g. they will have different headers, different MTUs, ...

Ethernet is used in LANs. PPP is used for the connection to the provider.